# How to get SQL Server table data completely by small parts without index

Tags: sql-server, dump

I have SQL Server table without any indexes, and I cannot add them. There are millions of records in that table, and I can not get all records with single query because of insufficient memory.

How can I get all records in small portions - for example 100 records per portion?

Comment: This sounds like an exam question, not something that would actually occur in the real world.

Answer (score 1):

How are you attempting to read the records? If you use a `SqlDataReader`, then you should not have any out of memory problems.

---

```
const string QUERY = "SELECT * FROM MyTable";
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(CONNECTION_STRING))
{
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(QUERY, conn))
    {
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                // Use properties and methods of the reader to access the current row
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This passes you one row at a time across the database connection. The connection will do the buffering for you, bringing multiple rows from the database, and passing them to you one at a time.

Comment: And it will not consume extra memory at both client&server sides? If it just caches whole table at client side - it is bad for me. If it creates temporary table with index and uses it - it is also not good because in that case it is more convinient for me to handle such table in my own way.

How then it works without indexes in table? Can it's work be reproduced using only usual SQL queryes on open SqlConnection?

Comment: This does not work for big tables (with some millions of records - exception saying that "the table is too big" is thrown.

Comment: Please post the complete exception. Post ex.ToString().

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the rare cases when a cursor can be used on its actual purpose.

You can create a statiс cursor (which will create a copy of the table data, but in the server's temporary db rather than on the client side, and sort it) and browse this cursor.

Answer (score 0):

The one solution is - to select all table that i need to dump, into temporary table with identity column. It is... acceptable solution, since i have separate application and database servers, and DB server has enough memory for this. But probably there is more effective solution?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use a server side cursor, as Quassnoi already suggested. The drawback of that is that it will have to be a static cursor which means a copy of the entire table will be created in tempdb.

Another solution is to process the client side in a stream oriented fashion, row by row (ie. client side cursor):

```
 using(SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess))
 {
   while (rdr.Read())
   {
     -- process one row here
   }
 }
```

This way you can process a big row set without burning out all your client side memory.